# C code stops after if statement inside while loop

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that assigns the user one of three questions at random. I figured out that part however I want to make it so that after they correctly answer their assigned question that they are asked if they want to take another one.

```
int main(void) {

    srand(time(0));

    int luckyNumber;
    int quizNumber;
    int score;
    int totalScore;
    int averageScore;
    int attempts;
    char answer1;
    char answer2;
    char answer3;
    char opt1;
    char loop = 'y';

    printf("Welcome to the quiz program!\n");

    while(loop == 'y') {
        printf("Please enter a lucky number between 1 and 9: ");

        scanf("%d", &luckyNumber);

        quizNumber = rand() % 3 + 1;

        printf("Your quiz number is %d\n", quizNumber);

        if (quizNumber == quizNumber) {
            while (score != 5) { 

                printf("Quiz 1\n");  
                printf("A. True\n");
                printf("B. False\n");
                printf("Enter your answer: ");
                scanf(" %c", &answer1);
            
                if (answer1 == 'B' || answer1 == 'b') {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    score = score + 5;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("Incorrect!, Try again.\n");  
                    printf("\n");       
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    printf("Would you like to go again y/n?");
    scanf("%c", &loop);
        if (loop != 'y')
            loop = 'n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is after I compile the code, it stops when the correct answer is input rather than going on to ask if the user would like to do another quiz.

Comment: The second `break` immediately drops you out of your `while` loop to the return statement, so you never get to that `printf`. On a side note, why are you comparing `quizNumber == quizNumber`?

Comment: There's a ton of uninitialized variables here and undefined behaviour as a result.

Comment: Why do you `break` all over the place? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `if (quizNumber == quizNumber)` will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &loop);` -> `scanf(" %c", &loop);`

Comment: for the sake of testing, I set if (quizNumber == quizNumber) because of the random generation of the quiz numbers. In the future they would be set to quizNumber == 1, quizNumber == 2, quizNumber == 3. also the other uninitialized variables are for later questions, I was just trying to get everything working before I went and wrote all the questions.

Comment: Advice: Separate each question into its own function (or a general purpose question/answer function). Don't write a long if/else if/else if/else that scrolls for 300 lines. No one wants to scroll past 17 questions to see what else happens at the bottom of the loop. "Comparimenatlise" things